# P/Invoke pointer to pointer?

Tags: .net, pinvoke

While updating a third party library to work correctly on x64 (it's using `int` for pointers), I was looking at the P/Invoke signatures.

One of them requires

```
__out  LPSCARDCONTEXT phContext
```

This is defined in WinSCard.h

```
typedef ULONG_PTR SCARDCONTEXT;
typedef SCARDCONTEXT *PSCARDCONTEXT, *LPSCARDCONTEXT;
```

I'm not really familiar with C++, so correct me if I'm wrong. This means `LPSCARDCONTEXT` is a pointer to a `ULONG_PTR`, which is a pointer too. This also explains why `IntPtr phContext` doesn't work and `ref IntPtr phContext` does work, in the P/Invoke signature.

I'm confused by the design. Why is a pointer to a pointer needed/used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I think @David Hefferman is absolutely right there's a second part to the question which he did not address.

The part which he did not talk about is that pointers to pointers do exist as they are sometimes used to return pointers from function as arguments. Here's a more detailed [discussion about the benefits of pointers-to-pointers](http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx8.html).

Also, the reason you need to use the `ref` keyword in order to correctly marshal the data to-from your C# code is that unless you use ref, the data is only marshaled *into* the native code. If you need to receive the modified value into your argument (which is indicated by the fact that the variable is declared as a pointer) then you need to use `ref` or `out` to indicate to the P/Invoke API that you need the data marshaled *out* of the native code after the function is done executing.

Comment: I don't think your final paragraph is right.  `SCARDCONTEXT` feels to me as thought it is an opaque handle type. Then when a parameter with signature `__out  LPSCARDCONTEXT phContext` is used that suggests using a pointer to pass by reference.  I suspect that this is really C style code and that a pass by reference is not used because C only has pass by value.

Comment: Accepted this as the answer. I won't comment on the other part of the answer/discussion.

Comment: @Stijn The main problem with this is that the body of the answer is the final paragraph which uses the term marshal incorrectly. Use of `ref` (and anyway it should be `out` rather than `ref` but that's a side issue) does not result in marshalling. All it does it ensure that the value of the parameter, the `IntPtr` is passed back to the caller. There's no marshalling here.

Comment: Then should I undo the accept, and when @Miky removes that paragraph I can accept it again?

Comment: @Stijn I'm not so fussed about the accept tick, I just wanted to leave comments for other readers so that they weren't misled by this slip. I'm sure it's just loose terminology from Miky, but the word *marshal* has a very particular meaning in this setting. I also don't see what you've got against my answer!!  ;-)  Perhaps you don't like the fact that I pointed out that you'd made a mistake!

Comment: Nothing against your answer, the essence of the question is why/when a pointer to a pointer is used. The rest is context. I'm glad for the explanation in your answer, it did help me understand this all.

Comment: @Stijn, I'm glad my answer helped you. @David - I don't think I've used the terminology incorrectly. Although it may not be modifying the data, the Interop marshaller is involved when P/Invoke APIs are used. So for the sake of the argument I think we can call it marshalling. See this overview for the reasoning: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eaw10et3%28VS.71%29.aspx

Comment: @Miky I know what you meant I just think you expressed it badly. All you meant to say was that a C# ref parameter is equivalent to a C++ reference parameter. In C you don't have reference parameters, all parameter passing is by value, and so you need to pass an address by value to achieve the same effect.

Answer (score 3):

Your understanding is not quite right. `ULONG_PTR` is an unsigned integer type that is at least as wide as a pointer. This means that you can cast from any pointer to `ULONG_PTR` and back again without losing information.

The naming of `ULONG_PTR` has clearly tricked you into believing that it *represents* a pointer when in fact the intention is to indicate that it is as *wide* as a pointer.

You can think of `ULONG_PTR` as the C++ equivalent to `UIntPtr`.

My guess is that your function is returning from native to managed a `SCARDCONTEXT` value.  You would P/Invoke it like this:

```
[DLLImport(...)]
void MyFunc(out IntPtr Context);
```

I'm electing to use `IntPtr` rather than `UIntPtr` since I guess you never need to do anything with the value because this is probably an opaque handle.  And `IntPtr` is generally to be preferred to `UIntPtr` since it is CLS-compliant.

Comment: I have changed the signature to use *ref UIntPtr phContext*, it still seems to work and I guess it makes more sense than a negative number as a pointer. +1

Comment: @Stijn See my updated answer. I think actually you should use `out` rather than `ref`.

Answer (score 3):

Some thoughts on understanding the API.

Defining `SCARDCONTEXT` as a `ULONG_PTR` is a common technique for concealing precisely what the pointer is pointing to. Its not really a pointer to a LONG, its an 'unsigned long' containing a pointer to some structure that you don't have the definition of because you don't need it (an [opaque type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_data_type)). When you pass a `SCARDCONTEXT` to one of the smartcard functions it internally casts to to a pointer to the opaque structure. And when it returns one of these pointers to you then it gets cast to `SCARDCONTEXT`first.

This is a common encapsulation technique in C-based APIs because the operations that you can perform on a `SCARDCONTEXT` exist separately from the definition of `SCARDCONTEXT`, not as bound member functions as they would in an object-based language. As [@DavidHeffernan explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6033346/p-invoke-pointer-to-pointer/6033387#6033387), this works because  `ULONG_PTR` is really an `unsigned long`, which can contain a pointer.

The point of all this is that you can ignore the fact that `SCARDCONTEXT` contains a pointer. Just treat it as an opaque value. Then `PSCARDCONTEXT` and `LPSCARDCONTEXT` become easier to understand because they're just pointers to an opaque value. No need to bother with pointers to pointers.

Comment: So when writing native code, the developer is not exposed to the meaning of SCARDCONTEXT, but when writing managed code, the developer (writing the P/Invoke part) is exposed to the meaning. Correct?

Comment: @Stijn  In both managed an unmanaged code, `SCARDCONTEXT` is just a value. It doesn't really have a 'meaning' other than identifying something. But in p/invoking windows api functions (which, unless they are com-based, are always C-style function-orientated) from .net )object-oriented) you are bridging across two different styles of code. So you have to be conscious of code 'idioms' used in the windows api. Thats what I was trying to explain. Others have done a good job of explaining why pointers are used (to return a value from the function) and what the p/invoke signature should be.

Comment: @Stijn  By the way, and in case you're not aware of it, you can find a fairly complete set of p/invoke function signatures at [pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net). Click the 'winscard' entry on the left-side navigation bar to see the functions that people have contributed signatures for.